# Prove that the addition of two unit vectors bisect the angle between the vectors themselves

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, vectors

Here is a picture for clarity:

[image]

[image]

So here is what I attempted:

- $a \dot{} b = |a||b|\cos(\theta)$
- $a \dot{} (\hat{a}+\hat{b})$ $= |a||\hat{a}+\hat{b}|\cos(\gamma)$
- $a \dot{}$ $(\frac{a}{|a|} + \frac{b}{|b|})$ $= |a| |\hat{a}+\hat{b}| \cos(\gamma)$
- $|a| + a \dot{} \hat{b}$ $= |a| |\hat{a}+\hat{b}| \cos(\gamma)$
- $|a| + |a| \cos(\theta)$ $= |a| |\hat{a}+\hat{b}| \cos(\gamma)$
- $1 + \cos(\theta)$ $= |\hat{a}+\hat{b}| \cos(\gamma)$

Ok so where can I go from here?

Answer (score 2):

Let $a+b$ make angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with vectors $a$ and $b$ respectively.

Now $$a\cdot(a+b)=a\cdot b+b\cdot b=a\cdot b+1$$

Likewise, $$b\cdot (a+b)=a\cdot b+1$$

So $$a\cdot(a+b)=b\cdot(a+b)$$
$$\implies|a||a+b|\cos \alpha=|b||a+b|\cos \beta$$

and we know $|a|=|b|$

Hence $\alpha=\beta$

Comment: Minor edit: In the second line, it should be $b\cdot(a+b)$.

Comment: @Dimension Entangled you are right - thanks for that!